# What are the differences between fn(b: Box<dyn Trait>) and fn<T: Trait>(b: &mut T) in Rust?

Tags: rust

What are the differences between `fn(b: &mut Box<dyn Trait>)` and `fn<T: Trait>(b: &mut T)` in Rust?

What is the difference in memory usage and why?

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Actually no, I shouldve been more clear. I'm more interested in the difference of memory usage.

Comment: I think that's covered in the linked question. But there's no difference in the _amount_ of memory used (save for a couple of pointers) - the box just has an extra pointer indirection via the heap

Comment: The generic function has no overhead (see the Traits section of the TRPL) where the one with Box has one pointer indirection of overhead. Also, did you mean to write `Box<dyn Trait>`?

Comment: There are multiple differences between these two things (note that you could also write `fn(b: &mut dyn Trait)` or `fn<T: Trait>(b: &mut Box<T>)`, with still different semantics). The difference between `&mut` and `Box` is described in the answer that's already linked; the difference between `<T: Trait>` and `dyn Trait` is addressed in questions such as [What makes something a “trait object”?](/q/27567849/3650362).

Comment: Also see [How to write a Rust function that takes an iterator?](/q/34969902/3650362) (`Iterator` being an example of a trait)

Comment: Memory usage is... complicated to analyze, because these are semantically different signatures; you might as well ask whether a function that takes `f64` uses more memory than one that takes `i64`... it depends on the function.

Comment: @trentcl PeterHall BradyDean Thanks for all the given input and links, I've done a bit of research and have read the links and have eventually found this link https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html and have gained a bit more understanding about the subject. Thanks again.